How can I get absolute position of line in react-konva
Hi I'm trying to drag a line and save the current position of line after dragged, when I use node.getAbsolutePosition() method, I get the relative position from the last position of my line, but I've read the documentary it says node.getAbsolutePosition() return absolute position relative to top-left corner of canvas
<Line
   points={[0,0,100,100]}
   stroke="blue"
   strokeWidth={5}
   onDragMove={(e) => {console.log(e.target.getAbsolutePosition())}}
   draggable
 />

is there other way to get the absolute position of line?
